# What (small) computer chips are able to run JCOP and are EMV compatible?

Tags: java, smartcard, emv

NXP Semiconductors has the Smartmx2 P60 that is able to run JCOP3 and is compatible with EMV.

Now I wonder where one can find other tiny chips that are capable of the same thing but perhaps a bit slower or some other trade-off?

I am in search of a chip that is smaller than the P60 but is still perfectly functional.

I have tried Google but to no avail.

Comment: Unfortunately, "where can I find a product that does X?" is off-topic here.